# HTML5 URL Input Box without Protocol

Tags: url, html, firefox4

When you use a `input` type of `url` instead of the standard `text`. Firefox 4 will not submit the form without `http://` or `https://` in the input box.

All I'm after is a URL without the protocol such as `www.google.com` not `http://www.google.com`. Is there a parameter to do this or any other way (preferably without JavaScript)?

Answer (score 3):

use the html5 novalidate attribute on the form, e.g.

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
   ...
</form>
```

this will give you the nice keyboard on mobile devices and let you do your own validation

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-novalidate

Answer (score -1):

I use [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) for all my regular expression creation needs.  They have a number of pre-defined regular expressions.

You might be able to reverse engineer this a little:
`(https?://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?`

Comment: Does not allow .museum and no IDN's.